# Display category name on page

Tags: channel-entries, categories, category-name

I have my category links:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="pages" category_group="3"}
        <a href="{path='work/cat-landing'}">{category_name}</a>
        {if category_description}{category_description}{/if}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

I'm trying to display the name of the category that was clicked on "cat-landing" template.

Using the following code, but that's just outputting all the categories I have selected in my entries.

```
{categories} {category_name}{/categories}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using standard category url methods, you can just use the [category heading tag](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/category_heading.html).